# How to check if an Angular2 3.0.0-rc.1 router link is not active?

Tags: angular

I know I can apply a CSS class when a route is active by using

```
<a [routerLink]="/user/bob" routerLinkActive="active-link">Bob</a>
```

but was wondering what the best way to apply a class when a specific router component is not active would be.

Comment: Use plain css to style non active links and your `active-link` class can override those styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the not() operator to select all instances of your element that don't have the 'active-link' class on it.

```
a.<your-class>:not('.active-link') {}
```